# Doesn't send func with delay, python

Tags: python, datetime, scheduled-tasks

Scheduler must send message at exect time, but it works without delay... what is wrong?

```
import os
import time
import schedule
from slackclient import SlackClient

BOT_NAME = "nagfhght"
SLACK_API_TOKEN = "xoxb-ghhghgghhfe"
BOT_ID = "hgfhfghfg"

sc = SlackClient(SLACK_API_TOKEN)


def send_message(text):
    sc.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel="#madchickens",
        text=text
    )


schedule.every().weekday.at("14:16").do(send_message, send_message("here time work"))
```

Comment: You are calling the function `send_message` in your last line. What you probably want is `(...).do(send_message, "here time work")`.

Comment: Thank you! But same problem, it send message write at moment, not on written time